# add a new textbox onclick in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm working on a project in php. I've a slider and an add button. If I click on the add button, a new slider along with another add button and a delete button will display. If I click on add button, the same cycle will go on and if I click on the delete button, the same line will disappear.
I've tried this one:

```
<div id="time">
<div id="slider-range1"></div>
<span id="utility2"></span>
<a class="add_time" href="#">Add</a>
</div>

$("#time").delegate(".add_time", "click", function(){
    var content =  '<div>'
                   +'<div id="slider-range2"></div>'
                   +'<span id="input_time1"></span>'
                   +'<a class="del_time" href="#">Delete</a>'
                   +'<a class="add_time" href="#">Add</a>'
                   +'</div>';
    $("#time").append(content);
    return false;
});

$("#time").delegate(".del_time", "click", function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Do not use ID use class because ID must be unique for each DOM...and by adding it dynamically you no longer have unique ID for each dom.

Comment: thanks @DipeshParmar i've used that one also but it is not displaying the slider except the two buttons.

Comment: can you please create fiddle for that so i can solve it..

Comment: What is the problem exactly. Despite the poor markup, your code works just fine? What do you want to do? Where does the AJAX come into things?

Comment: @DipeshParmar http://jsfiddle.net/3UnSP/2/

Comment: @Jeemusu http://jsfiddle.net/3UnSP/2/

Comment: @user2756295 So what was the question?

Answer (score 0):

You also can try to display or not the specific div that you wish or not to show up, as for example:

```
<div id="time">
<div id="slider-range1"></div>
<span id="utility2"></span>
<a class="add_time" href="#">Add</a>
<div id="slider" style="display:none;">'
    <div id="slider-range2"></div>'
    <span id="input_time1"></span>'
    <a class="del_time" href="#">Delete</a>'
    <a class="add_time" href="#">Add</a>'
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.add_time').click(function() {
    $("#slider").css("display","block");
});

});
```

You also can hide the slider defining the display to none in the javascript